# Why Array helper Filter is returning a null value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to JavaScript and while learning it trying to filter an employee based on education but my filter is returning a null value. Can anyone help me understand why is this so?

```js
var employeeEdu = [{education: 'Masters'}];
 
var employees = [{id: 1, age: 35, name: 'James', dept: 'IT', education: 'Masters'},
                {id: 2, age: 25, name: 'David', dept: 'Accounts', education: 'High School'},
                {id: 3, age: 45,name: 'Tim', dept: 'HR', education: 'Graduate'}, 
                {id: 4, age: 50,name: 'Vinod', dept: 'IT', education: 'PHD'}];

function chooseQualified(arrEmployee, empEducation) {
  return arrEmployee.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.education === empEducation.education;
    //  return emp.education === 'Masters';
  });
}

console.log(chooseQualified(employees, employeeEdu));
```

Comment: It appears to return an empty array, not `null`.

Comment: To find the problem yourself, you can add more `console.log()` statements in your code. For more tips on debugging your own code, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: That's correct. It was returning undefined, not null. Thanks for sharing the link. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `employeeEdu` is an array, and `employeeEdu.education` is undefined. What you need to do is to checkout `employeeEdu[0].education`:

```js
var employeeEdu = [{education: 'Masters'}];
 
var employees = [{"id":1,"age":35,"name":"James","dept":"IT","education":"Masters"},{"id":2,"age":25,"name":"David","dept":"Accounts","education":"High School"},{"id":3,"age":45,"name":"Tim","dept":"HR","education":"Graduate"},{"id":4,"age":50,"name":"Vinod","dept":"IT","education":"PHD"}];

function chooseQualified(arrEmployee, empEducation) {
  return arrEmployee.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.education === empEducation[0].education;
    //  return emp.education === 'Masters';
  });
}

console.log(chooseQualified(employees, employeeEdu));
```

Another solution is to remove the wrapping array:

```
employeeEdu = {education: 'Masters'};
```

Comment: Or alternatively, assign `employeeEdu` as an object, or just pass in the education string directly to the function.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out understanding the issue. It worked when I tried based on your solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ori Drori says, employeeEdu is an array, so empEducation.education is undefined, but empEducation[0].education is 'Masters'. I suggest that employeeEdu be a object instead of array, like below code. `var employeeEdu = {education: 'Masters'};`

```js
var employeeEdu = {education: 'Masters'};
 
var employees = [{id: 1, age: 35, name: 'James', dept: 'IT', education: 'Masters'},
                {id: 2, age: 25, name: 'David', dept: 'Accounts', education: 'High School'},
                {id: 3, age: 45,name: 'Tim', dept: 'HR', education: 'Graduate'}, 
                {id: 4, age: 50,name: 'Vinod', dept: 'IT', education: 'PHD'}];

function chooseQualified(arrEmployee, empEducation) {
  return arrEmployee.filter(function(emp) {
    return emp.education === empEducation.education;
    //  return emp.education === 'Masters';
  });
}

console.log(chooseQualified(employees, employeeEdu));
```

Comment: Alternatively, employeeEdu can be just a string.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /* @Params: 
>  * array0 [Array of Objects]: Array to search through.
>  * array1 [Array of Objects]: Array with the key/value to search for.
>  * key [String]: Key of the object in array1.
>  * index [Number](optional): Index of array1. default: 0.    
>  */
>  // Returns a new array of objects witch matched by key/value from the two given arrays.
> function findByKV(array0, array1, key, index = 0) {
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> // Get the value of the key to be searched for
> var value = array1[index][key];
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> // Filter the array to be searched obj is each Object in array1
> ```
>
> [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
>
> ```
> array0.filter(function(obj) {
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> // Get each obj key of array0 and ...
> ```
>
> [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
>
> ```
> return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> // ...return true if at least one String value matches the value of the key in array1
> ```
>
> [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
>
> ```
>  return obj[key].toString().indexOf(value) != -1;
> ```

```js
var target0 = [{education: 'Masters'}];

var target1 = [{dept: 'IT',education: ''}];

var employees = [
  {id: 1,age: 35,name: 'James',dept: 'IT',education: 'Masters'}, 
  {id: 2,age: 25,name: 'David',dept: 'Accounts',education: 'High School'}, 
  {id: 3,age: 45,name: 'Tim',dept: 'HR',education: 'Graduate'}, 
  {id: 4,age: 50,name: 'Vinod',dept: 'IT',education: 'PHD'}, 
  {id: 5,age: 46,name: 'Matt',dept: 'IT',education: 'Masters'}
];

function findByKV(array0, array1, key, index = 0) {
  var value = array1[index][key];
  var array2 = array0.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
      return obj[key].toString().indexOf(value) != -1;
    });
  });
  return array2;
}

var result0 = findByKV(employees, target0, 'education');
var result1 = findByKV(employees, target1, 'dept');

console.log('Found targrt0: ' + JSON.stringify(result0, null, 2));
console.log('Found target1: ' + JSON.stringify(result1, null, 2));
```